# Android Gradle save log output to file

Tags: android-gradle-plugin

Using Android and Gradle how can I save the console messages of gradlew tasks to a file? For example when running 'gradlew connectedCheck -i' how do I save the run times and any failures to a file?

Answer (score 9):

In bash/command line run:

```
 ./gradlew connectedCheck -i 2>&1 | tee file.txt
```

Comment: What does `-i 2>&1` mean?

Comment: `2>&1` redirects the standard error `stderr` to the standard output `stdout` so basically we merge the two outputs to the file. 
`-i` sets the log level to info for Gradle.

Answer (score 0):

In Powershell on Windows where tee is typically not available, you can do the same thing with the normal redirection operator (looks similar to BASH, but does indeed work):

`./gradlew connectedCheck -i 2>&1 > file.txt`

As far as I know this should work all the way back to Powershell 2.0, only because we still use it at work on some of our older servers. I can't find docs for anything older than v3.0, for which the documentation is here:

[about_Redirection | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection?view=powershell-3.0)

Comment: Powershell 2.0 was deprecated in 2017: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/windows-powershell-2-0-deprecation/