# Android Studio - log file of Gradle build

Tags: android-studio

i'm using Android Studio version 1.1.0 and every time i want to build my app, Android Studio is freezing. I have to close the program over my task manager.

I know that Gradle is guilty but i can't read the Gradle build messages. Is there a log file anywhere? I can't find something. I'm a OS X user. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've found similar thread here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28616214/1150795. There's an example with `connectedCheck` command, but in your case, you can simply use `build` command and build your project via CLI like that:

```
./gradlew build -i 2>&1 | tee file.txt
```

I've checked it with Android Build Tools 1.1.0 on Linux (Ubuntu). It works and it should work on OS X as well. Log from Gradle will be saved in `file.txt` file.

You can also run `clean` command before when something will go wrong with your build.

```
./gradlew clean build -i 2>&1 | tee file.txt
```